# Go from one id to another using location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To start off here is my code:

```
var $this = $(this);

// Move Next.
$('<div class ="right">Next</div>')
     .appendTo($this)
     .on('click', function() {
          location.hash = '#work';
     });
// Move Previous.
$('<div class ="left">Previous</div>')
     .appendTo($this)
     .on('click', function() {
          location.hash = '#intro';
     });
```

I would like to move from one id tag to another using buttons to click. The #work is just the next article id that I want to pop up, but there is more after that and I want it to just go to the next article when I click the next button. The same goes for the back button. I would also like to once it reaches the end it goes back to the beginning or the button goes to display: none. If anyone can help me solve this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you considered creating links of the form `<a href="#id">`?

Comment: I have link buttons but when the article comes up like modal I want to be able to go from one to the next without having to close and reopen.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange).

Comment: You need **Carousel** for turning to beginning when it reaches the end.

Comment: Now I know you can put a carousel inside of a modal but what about a modal in a carousel, I mean it's generally the same principle just instead of images it's an article.